# Parsing object in PHP not working

Tags: php

I'm using this to get my response (only relevant code below):

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  $result=curl_exec ($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);
  echo $result;
  $my_resp = $result['total_count'];
  var_dump($my_resp);
```

`echo $result` gives me an object that appears to be valid JSON. Like this:

```
{
"total_count": 1
}
```

However, `$my_resp` comes back as `NULL`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does `var_dump($result);` show you (instead of the `echo`)?  What about `var_dump(json_decode($result, true));`?

Comment: @NathanDavis That was a copy/paste typo. Should be `$result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn it into an object from a string

```
$result = json_decode( curl_exec($ch));
```

or an associative array

```
$result = json_decode( curl_exec($ch), true );
```

Comment: The second one gave me back `int(1)` which is strange. The first one threw an error about "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" referring to the `$my_resp` line.

Comment: My mistake. The second yielded `NULL`

Comment: @jonmrich: That's because when you use the 1st one, you are getting back an object, not an array.  With the 1st one, you need to do: `$my_resp = $response->total_count;`.

Comment: `$result = json_decode( curl_exec($ch));
 $my_resp = $result->total_count;` still returns NULL

Comment: Just realized that `int(1)` is exactly the response I was looking for. `total_count` equals `1` when it's successful. So, you're first option plus what's in your comment worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: json_decode( curl_exec($ch)); $my_resp = $result->total_count; is correct, unless there is something wrong with the JSON being returned in from the curl request.  Check the error with json_last_error();

Answer (score 0):

If it is JSON, you should `json_decode()` it before trying to read fields.

Comment: This is still yielding `NULL` for me.